# Powercenter Parametrization error

Tags: parameters, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to parametrize expression variables in expression transformation. My expressions are as follows:

IN(EMP_DEPT_CD, (‘12WE3’,’LKOW23’,’PO234’,’IULYT34’),0)

RTRIM(LTRIM(EMP_TERM_CD))=‘1234’ AND EMP_TERM_DT > SYSDATE

(OR THE POST SESSION COMMAND WILL REPLACE THIS SYSDATE BY SYSDATE - 8 MONTHS)

I replaced the expressions as follows:

IN(EMP_DEPT_CD, $$EMP_CD_LIST,0)

RTRIM(LTRIM(EMP_TERM_CD))=‘1234’ AND EMP_TERM_DT > $$EMP_DT

My parameter file contains these variables as:

$$EMP_DT = SYSDATE

$$EMP_CD_LIST=(‘12WE3’,’LKOW23’,’PO234’,’IULYT34’)

I am getting transformation initialization error, and parsing error. Also, i  have set in mapping variables and parameters Isexprvar = true and the the type as parameter. I apologize if i am using any wrong terms here as i am new to parametrization.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your parameter file, have you specified the proper scope as shown in the [article](http://etl-tools.info/informatica/parameters_variables.html).. also I am thinking your `$$EMP_DT` and `$$EMP_CD_LIST` are on different lines and not as shown in the question on the same line, which will not work

Comment: sorry, this is a mistake, let me edit. they are indeed on different lines and are different expressions assigned to different ports.

Comment: could you also post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Transformation parse Fatal error; transformation stopped..... TE_7002 ...[PM Parse Error>>syntax error .....[IN(EMP_DEPT_CD, (‘12WE3’,<<<<’LKOW23’,’PO234’,’IULYT34’),0]

Comment: Have you tried it without the parentheses like`$$EMP_CD_LIST=‘12WE3’,’LKOW23’,’PO234’,’IULYT34’`?

Comment: It works without parenthesis but i am concerned that it will correctly work for all the values, if it is not correctly working, i shall post again. Thanks anyways

Comment: First of all: have you confirmed that your syntax (without using parameters) works? According to documentation instead of using IN(EMP_DEPT_CD, (‘12WE3’,’LKOW23’,’PO234’,’IULYT34’),0) you should use IN(EMP_DEPT_CD,‘12WE3’,’LKOW23’,’PO234’,’IULYT34’,0).